# Get current term's ID

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

Im using the following code to get an array of children taxonomies and write them out with links in an unordered list.

```
    <?php
$termID = 10;
$taxonomyName = "products";
$termchildren = get_term_children( $termID, $taxonomyName );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName );
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the actual term (category) id so I can replace it on $termID and don't have to hardcode the id of the term.

Any help would be kindly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a function I use to list subterms:

```
/**
 * Lists all subentries of a taxonomy.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function ttt_get_subterms( $args = array () )
{
    if ( ! isset ( get_queried_object()->taxonomy ) )
    {
        return;
    }

    $options = array (
        'child_of'           => get_queried_object_id()
    ,   'echo'               => 0
    ,   'taxonomy'           => get_queried_object()->taxonomy
    ,   'title_li'           => FALSE
    ,   'use_desc_for_title' => FALSE
    );

    $settings = array_merge( $options, $args );

    $subtermlist = wp_list_categories( $settings );

    // Without results WP creates a dummy item. It doesn't contain links.
    ! empty ( $subtermlist ) and FALSE !== strpos( $subtermlist, '<a ' )
        and print "<ul class=subterms>$subtermlist</ul>";
}
```

Use it like [`wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories).

Avoid `get_term_by()`. It is very expensive and not necessary.

Comment: Works awesome and I get the terms listed just like wp_list_categories. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To get the Current term you can use `get_query_var( 'term' );` and to get the current taxonomy you can use `get_query_var( 'taxonomy' )` so you can do something like this:

```
$term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
$taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );
$termchildren = get_term_children( $current_term->term_id, $taxonomyName );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName );
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use : **term_exists**( $term, $taxonomy, $parent )

```
$term_id = term_exists( $term_name );
```

See [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists)

> Check if a given term exists and return the term ID
>
> Returns the term ID if no taxonomy was specified and the term exists.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current term ID, [use](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/):

```
$term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
```

[`get_query_var`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) cannot be used in thise case, since `term_id` is not in the [list](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) of vars available publicly.