# Get the object ID by URL

Tags: posts, oop

I have an URL (such as the URL `/sample-page/`), I need the corresponding object ID. How?

Answer (score 5):

Try this function:

```
url_to_postid( $url );
```

The [WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid) is your friend. A quick Google search could have provided the answer.

Comment: "A quick Google search could have provided the answer," which is why everyone is using StackExchange? This remark deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are valid, but just to add another (usually unknown, but very usefull ) method that is supplied by a function called :`get_page_by_path();`

```
$page =get_page_by_path('parent-page/sub-page');
```

It is worthy  to note that the path parameter can even take a SLUG as parameter.
Example :

```
$page = get_page_by_path('your-slug-of-page-to-exclude');
wp_list_pages('exclude='.$page->ID.'&title_li=');
```

then you could use `$page->ID`

Comment: Doesn't work, `$page-ID` returns error `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ....`

Comment: did you tried `$page->ID` or `$page-ID` ?

Comment: Good to know, although it does not work for an URL output by polylang's `pll_home_url()`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`get_queried_object_id()`](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=008094839757605916882:f6pwe-gmjka&ie=UTF-8&q=get_queried_object_id) a mapper for [`WP_Query::get_queried_object_id()`](http://xref.yoast.com/trunk/wp-includes/query.php.source.html#l2960).

Unlike `url_to_postid()` you don't have to know the URL and it works on taxonomies and custom post types too (if I remember this correct).

For a usage example see my [answer to **Get current term's ID**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/15289/73).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, only with custom post types. Unfortunately `url_to_postid( $url );` is not working with custom types, so I ended up using this function [bwp_url_to_postid($url)](http://betterwp.net/wordpress-tips/url_to_postid-for-custom-post-types/).
This function extend `url_to_postid( $url );` to work with custom post types.

If you have the permalink of the URL, then:

```
<?php $postLink = get_permalink($post_object->ID); ?>
<?php $postId = bwp_url_to_postid($link); ?>
<?php echo $postId ?>
```