# Check what is at URI (post, archive, etc...)

Tags: urls, parse

Is there a way or function where you can pass in a custom uri like

```
uri-part/uri-part2
```

and we can check what is under this address?

I want to check if a uri hosts a post, page, archive, category, tag, other taxonomy, custom post type archive or custom?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the object ID by URL](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49291/get-the-object-id-by-url)

Comment: This is not a duplicate - OP wants to effectively run `WP::parse_request` in a sandbox, _not_ just get the ID for a post.

Answer (score 4):

### Retrieve "type" of query from url: Previous suggestions

As noted in the linked answer, there's [`url_to_postid()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/url_to_postid/). This will just get you the *ID* of the object at that endpoint. Long story short, this function will only return an *ID* and then run a new `\WP_Query` to get the post type object from the DB and finally return the URl – if there is any and _if it is something of `is_singular` (a post, a page). So that function is not really helpful.

As mentioned in the comments, there's also:

```
$object = get_page_by_path( 
    'path/endpoint', 
    OBJECT|ARRAY_N|ARRAY_A,
    [ 'post', 'page', 'custom_post_type', '…' ]
);
```

which will run the following query:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent, post_type
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_name IN ( $in_string )
        AND post_type IN ( $post_types_string )
";
```

And again: Not helpful.

### WordPress Url to Query: Behind the scenes

This is how the process looks in WordPress

```
-------     --------------     -------------
| URl | --> | Query Vars | --> | \WP_Query |
-------     --------------     -------------
```

As mentioned by @TheDeadMedic, there's [`WP::parse_request()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp/parse_request/) that performs all the magic:

1. Retrieve all query vars
2. Fetch rewrite rules
3. Look up matches between the request and rewrite rules
4. Run registered query variables through a whitelist filter

While doing all that, the method actually fills an associative array: `WP::$query_vars`:

```
WP::$query_vars = [
    // $_POST or $_GET or query string variables `foo=bar&baz=dragons`
    // `custom` is not the actual name. The key will be named as the var.
    'custom'    => [],
    // An array of `$postTypeObject->query_var`s
    // Only those which are publicly queryable
    'post_type' => [],
    // Only publicly queryable taxonomies
    'taxonomy'  => [],
    'term'      => [],
    'name'      => [],
    'error'     => [],
    // …
];
```

At the end of that method, you have two filters. The first one is:

```
$this->query_vars = apply_filters( 'request', $this->query_vars );
```

where you have the above mentioned array present. Now you can start determining what kind of response your URl serves:

```
add_filter( 'request', function( Array $vars ) {
    // do whatever you need to do, depending on $vars in here
    return $vars;
} );
```

Examples of some `var_dump( $vars )`:

- Date based archive:

  ```
  array (size=2)
    'year' => string '2016' (length=4)
    'monthnum' => string '04' (length=2)
  ```
- Category archive:

  ```
  array (size=1)
    'category_name' => string 'alignment' (length=9)
  ```
- Hierarchical Taxonomy Child:

  ```
  array (size=1)
    'category_name' => string 'parent-category/child-category-05' (length=33)
  ```
- A posts single view – sticky is the same as default:

  ```
  array (size=2)
    'page' => string '' (length=0)
    'name' => string 'sticky' (length=6)
  ```