# get_term_children doesn't return an array of children terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I am trying to get the term children and then check if they exist to display them. But I get no IDs in return of get_term_children command. This is the code:

```
  $children = get_term_children($term->term_id, locations);
  echo $children;
```

$term is already defined and outputs well, "locations" taxonomy exists. The code returns me just an "Array" word, no list of child terms shows up.

I've got a similar code in my post archive pages and it works well returning me child categories in n/n/n/n/n format:

```
  $children = get_category_children($this_category->cat_ID);
  echo $children;
```

What's wrong with the first code? It should work as well as the second.

Comment: See also: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/15289/73 to list sub terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, try passing the Taxonomy as a string:

```
$children = get_term_children($term->term_id, 'locations');
```

The function get_category_children produces a string as return, so you can just echo it.
the function get_term_children, however, returns an array. To see the contents of the array, try

```
print_r( $children );
```

instead of echo.

The last thing to keep in mind is that a taxonomy does not need to be hierarchical - for example the built in tags. Be sure your "locations" is organized hierarchical, otherwise get_term_children won't work for you in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, fischi. My taxonomy is hierarchical, of course. I think I've got the thing, get_category_children and get_term_children return different types of data, that's why echo doesn't work. I tried to output the array via print_r, and it worked well.

My problem is I want to check if term has children. For category I have this code:

if (get_category_children($this_category->cat_ID) != "")

And what kind of code could you suggest for a taxonomy term?

Comment: Kinda solved it as well: if (get_term_children($term->term_id, 'locations') != null). Works fine. Thank you again.