# Can you have seperate sidebars for multiple taxonomy archives?

Tags: taxonomy, sidebar

I have a site that uses multiple query taxonomy archives.

i.e www.sitename.com/taxonomy1/taxonomy2/taxonomy3

Is there a plugin or method to create a dedicated sidebar for each queried taxonomy archive?

Essentially, there will be 1000 or so archives and i would like to be able to create a unique sidebar for each.  Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had luck dynamically creating sidebars using a foreach loop. You'd do something like this (untested) in your functions.php file:

```
$my_terms = get_terms( 'my_taxonomy_name' );
if( ! is_wp_error( $my_terms ) ) {
    foreach( $my_terms as $term ) {
        register_sidebar(
            'name' => $term->name . ' Archive Sidebar',
            'id' => 'archive_sidebar_' . $term->term_id
        );
    }
}
```

Then, in your taxonomy-my_taxonomy_name.php template file, you'd use something like this (untested) to get your sidebar (some code borrowed from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/15287/9844)):

```
<?php
$term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
$taxonomy_name = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy_name );
dynamic_sidebar( 'archive_sidebar_' . $current_term->term_id );
?>
```

Now, having said all that, I question whether this is a good idea. Assuming that generating 1000 sidebars doesn't have a negative performance affect on WordPress (which is a BIG assumption), the UI for the backend user would be terrible. I can't imagine finding the sidebar I actually wanted to use.

While it would be confusing still, I'd encourage you to use [Widget Logic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/) or, if you have non-code-savvy users, [Widget Logic Visual](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic-visual/).

Alternately, drop the whole idea of widgets sidebars and accomplish whatever you need by just using `get_query_var()` to figure out which term archive you're on in the template and then execute some context-aware code in the template file.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will actually take you last bit of advice and use a query to generate the content in one sidebar.  This will generate the required results based on the archive.  It wil be much easier to handle than all those sidebars : )

Comment: @PaulB Sounds like a good idea! You had me worried there. If this answered your question, make sure to accept it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this -

http://www.wordpressguide.in/want-different-sidebar-for-different-category.html

its easy and simple !

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Answers! [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.